Showing a space of functions is Hilbert
Let $X$ be a set, $K$ a mapping of positive type of $X\times X$ into $C$, that is, for any finite sequence $(x_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ in $X$, the map
$$((\lambda_i),(\mu_i))\mapsto\sum_{i,j}K(x_i,x_j)\lambda_i\overline{\mu_j}$$
is a Hermitian form from $\mathbb C^{2n}$ to $\mathbb C$.
Now let $E$ be the set of mappings $u:X\rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that there exists a real number $a\ge 0$ having the property that the mapping
$$(x,y)\mapsto aK(x,y)-u(x)\overline{u(y)}$$ is of positive type; let $m(u)$ be the smallest of all real number $a$ having that property (which clearly exists).
Show that $E$ is a Banach space with $\sqrt{m(u)}$ being the norm and $m(u+v)+m(u-v)\ge2(m(u)+m(v))$, so that there is a inner product induced by this norm which makes it Hilbert.
This is problem 6.3.8 on Dieudonné's Treatise on Analysis, Volume I. I have shown that
$$\sum_{i,j}u(x_i)\overline{u(x_j)}\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}=\left|\sum_iu(x_i)\lambda_i\right|^2$$ and that
$E$ is a Banach space by the inequality $|u(x)|^2\le K(x,x)m(u)$. The first part of the original problem asks to show $m(u)$ is the smallest $c$ such that for any finite sequence $(x_i)$ in $X$, any $(\lambda_i)$ in $\mathbb C$, and any complex number $\mu$, the inequality
$$\begin{equation}\tag{1}\sum_{i,j}K(x_i,x_j)\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}+c\mu\overline{\mu}+2{\text{Re}}\left(\sum_i u(x_i)\lambda_i\overline{\mu}\right)\ge0\end{equation}$$ holds, which I have also shown.
Yet I cannot figure out why $m(u+v)+m(u-v)\ge2(m(u)+m(v))$. I tried to show $2(m(u)-\varepsilon+m(v)-\varepsilon)-m(u-v)< m(u+v)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, that is to find a particular sequence of $(x_i)$ and $(\lambda_i)$ such that
$$\sum_{i,j}\Big(2(m(u)-\varepsilon)+2(m(v)-\varepsilon)-m(u-v)\Big)K(x_i,x_j)\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}-\left|\sum_i (u(x_i)+v(x_i))\lambda_i\right|^2<0$$ and by parallelogram law in $\mathbb C$ we have
$$\left|\sum_i (u(x_i)+v(x_i))\lambda_i\right|^2=2\left|\sum_i u(x_i)\lambda_i\right|^2+2\left|\sum_i v(x_i)\lambda_i\right|^2-\left|\sum_i (u(x_i)-v(x_i))\lambda_i\right|^2$$
But I don't know whether it is possible to construct $(x_i)$, $(\lambda_i)$ for which both $\sum (m(u)-\varepsilon)K(x_i,x_j)\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}-|\sum u(x_i)\lambda_i|^2$ and $\sum (m(v)-\varepsilon)K(x_i,x_j)\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}-|\sum v(x_i)\lambda_i|^2$ are both negative. Also I don't know how to exploit the inequality $(1)$. Any help would be appreciated.
